# How to move an object in straight line horizontally and vertically or in Inclined only in android surfaceview

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

i have a ball in my app its moving with the touch. I just want to make it move only horizontally, vertically or inclined *Not to move it zigzag* i tired following code an its working fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

Ourview v;
Bitmap ball;
float x,y;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = new Ourview(this);
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle_green);
    x = y = 0;
    setContentView(v);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    v.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}

public class Ourview extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOk = false;

    public Ourview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (isItOk == true){
            //perfom convas drawing
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(250, 10, 50, 100);
            c.drawBitmap(ball, x - (ball.getWidth()/2), y - (ball.getHeight()/2), null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

    }

    public void pause(){
        isItOk = false;
        while(true){
            try{
                t.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;

    }

    public void resume(){
        isItOk = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    switch(me.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

my ball is moving with the touch in any direction. i just want to restrict my ball to move in only horizontal or verticall or inclined direction, it should not move in zig zag patteren.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add some changes here:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        xStart = me.getX();
        yStart = me.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        xEnd = me.getX();
        yEnd = me.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
        break;
```

then draw it as a line on canvas:

```
c.drawLine(xStart,yStart,xEnd,YEnd,paint);
```

this will draw a straight line from **starting touch to end touch up** hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a test to see in which direction the ball should move. First, make a certain threshold value `t`. If the user moves more than `t` in the x or y direction, the move is registered. So calculate `deltaX = x - me.getX()` and `deltaY = y - me.getY()`.

If only `deltaX > t`, move the ball horizontally. If only `deltaY > t`, move the ball vertically.

If both are big enough, move the ball with the same amount in the x and y direction. This will make the ball move on the diagonal.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. seems good .plz paste a code snippt if u have i m new to touch programming in android